# IE9 and CSS dropdown list positioning

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9, hover

I have a pure CSS dropdown on our website. It works fine in Chrome, but in IE9, the child elements are to the right of the parent rather than below the parent.

CSS code:

```
/* drop down menus on front page */

ul#dropdown {
  font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #92008f;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Times;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul#dropdown li, ul#dropdown li ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 11pt;
    width: 140px;
    font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Times;
    color: #000000;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #efdaef;
    border: 1px solid #92008f;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  $author='STARK HOUSE'; 
include 'header.php'; ?>


<div id="wrapper">
     <ul id="dropdown">
<!--    STARK HOUSE -->
        <ul>
          <li><img src="images/downarrow.jpg" style="margin:0"> STARK HOUSE 
            <ul>
          <li><a href="pages/mysteryclub.html">Crime Book Club</a>
          <li><a href="http://www.ollerman.com/starkhouse/shnewsletter.html">Newsletter</a>
            </ul>
      </ul>
 <!--   FANTASY -->
        <ul>
          <li><img src="images/downarrow.jpg" style="margin:0">FANTASY
            <ul>
        <li><a href="blackwood.php">Algernon Blackwood</a>
          <li><a href="butzen.php">Catherine Butzen</a>
          <li><a href="constantine.php">Storm Constantine</a>
            </ul>
      </ul>
```

website: http://starkhousepress.com

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is with IE7, I tested with IE9 and works fine:

try the code bellow (I tested on IE 7 8 9 and other.. works fine)
HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="dropdown">
        <!--    STARK HOUSE -->
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="menu"><img src="http://starkhousepress.com/images/downarrow.jpg" style="margin:0"> STARK HOUSE </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="pages/mysteryclub.html">Crime Book Club</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ollerman.com/starkhouse/shnewsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--   FANTASY -->
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="menu"><img src="http://starkhousepress.com/images/downarrow.jpg" style="margin:0">FANTASY</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="blackwood.php">Algernon Blackwood</a></li>
                <li><a href="butzen.php">Catherine Butzen</a></li>
                <li><a href="constantine.php">Storm Constantine</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropdown {
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #92008f;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia, Times;
    z-index: 1;
}
.drop {
    display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
    vertical-align:top;
    *display:inline;
}
.drop ul{
    display:none;
}

.drop:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vRRw8/8/
I hope to help you